# Order of the local truncation error of Modified Euler (time integration)

Tags: numerical-methods, truncation-error

I've got quite a long question. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out, because I'm stuck at the moment.

I need to find the order of the local truncation error of Modified Euler, applied to the following system of equations:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2} - 1, & 0 < x < 1\\
\frac{\partial c(x=0,t)}{\partial x} = 0, \frac{\partial c(x=1), t}{\partial x} = 0, & t\geq 0\\
c(x,0) = f(x), & 0<x<1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

For the spatial discretization of the initial-boundary-value problem, central, second-order accurate nite-
differencing is applied. The mesh size is denoted by $h$ and the resulting semi-discrete system by
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mbox{d}y}{\mbox{d}t} = Ay + r
\end{equation}
(From a previous question, we calculated $A$, which has order $h^2$, and $r$.) 
I have written out M.E. for this equation, with $\tau$ as time step, as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
w^{j+1}&=w^j+\frac{\tau}{2}(Aw^j+r+A(w^j+\tau Aw^j +\tau r)+r)\\
&\mbox{ }...\\
&=w^j + (\tau + \frac{\tau^2}{2}A)(Aw^j + r)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Up to this, I am quite sure that it works out. Yet, from now on the trouble starts. My elaboration on the order of the local truncation error is as follows:

The local truncation error $\theta$ of this method can be computed:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:11}
\theta^{j+1} = \frac{c^{j+1} - z^{j+1}}{\tau},
\end{equation}
where $z^{j+1}$ is computed by applying the Modified Euler method to solution at time $t_j$ (given by $c^j$), hence
\begin{equation}\label{eq:12}
z^{j+1} = c^j + (\tau + \frac{\tau^2}{2}A)(Ac^j + r^j).
\end{equation}
Substituting this into the equation for $\theta^{j+1}$ yields:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:13}
\begin{split}
\theta^{j+1} &= \frac{c^{j+1} - c^j - (\tau + \frac{\tau^2}{2}A)(Ac^j +r^j)}{\tau}\\
&= \frac{c^{j+1} - c^j}{\tau} - (1+\frac{\tau}{2}A)(Ac^j + r^j)\\
&= \frac{\partial c^j}{\partial t} + \epsilon^j - (1+\frac{\tau}{2}A)((\frac{\partial^2 c^j}{\partial x^2} - 1) + \mu^j),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
in which
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon = \frac{\tau}{2}\frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial t^2}(x_i, \zeta_j), \zeta_j \in (t_j, t_{j+1}), \mbox{ and } \mu^j = -\frac{h^2}{12}\frac{\partial^4 c}{\partial x^4}(\xi_i, t_j), \xi \in (x_{i-1}, x_{i+1})
\end{equation*}
follow from the truncation errors of the numerical differentiation, equations (3.2) and (3.9) from the book. (These equations were given in my study book).

Hence, we get:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\theta^{j+1} &= \frac{\partial c^j}{\partial t} + \epsilon^j - (1+\frac{\tau}{2}A)((\frac{\partial^2 c^j}{\partial x^2} - 1) + \mu^j)\\
&= \epsilon^j - \frac{\tau}{2}A\frac{\partial^2c^j}{\partial x^2} - \mu^j - \frac{\tau}{2}A\mu^j,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
such that the method is of order $O(\tau + h^2)$

Now, I showed this to my professor and he said that the local truncation error should be of order $O(\tau^2 + h^2)$, but he studied this elaboration and could not find a mistake. He calculated the error with a different approach however.

I am wondering if you could help me with this 'solution'; is this a possible approach? And if it is, are there any flaws in it?

If you could help me, I'd be very happy since this problem has been causing me quite a lot of time already and I don't get it.

Thanks in advance!